# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: date.locale is not a function on Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, next.js, datepicker, antd, next.js13

How to resolve this "TypeError: date.locale"? I'm making an attempt to address this problem, but despite my efforts, I'm unable to find a solution.

API response:

```
{
  "birthday": "1999-03-09T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

change date format

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentRecord) {
      const formattedBirthday = dayjs(currentRecord.birthday)
        .tz("Asia/Dhaka")
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      setCurrentRecord({
        ...currentRecord,
        birthday: formattedBirthday,
      });

      form.setFieldsValue({
        birthday: moment(formattedBirthday),
      });
    }
  }, [currentRecord, setCurrentRecord, form]);
```

new date: `birthday: "1999-03-09"`

JSX -

```
<Form.Item
  label="Birthday"
  name="birthday"
  rules={[
    { required: true, message: "Please select a birthday!" }
  ]}
>
  <DatePicker
    style={{ width: "100%" }}
    placeholder="Select your birthday"
    format={dateFormat}
  />
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Can you post a Minimal, reproducible example?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there needs to be a pass **date** as an **object**

here is the code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (currentRecord) {
      const formattedBirthday = dayjs(currentRecord.birthday);
      const updatedRecord = {
        ...currentRecord,
        birthday: formattedBirthday,
      };
      form.setFieldsValue(updatedRecord);
    }
  }, [currentRecord]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `moment` with `dayjs`. Following [docs](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-time-related-controls) you should use only `dayjs` to handle time related values:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentRecord) {
      const formattedBirthday = dayjs(currentRecord.birthday)
        .tz("Asia/Dhaka")
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD");

      setCurrentRecord({
        ...currentRecord,
        birthday: formattedBirthday
      });

      form.setFieldsValue({
        birthday: formattedBirthday // removed moment
      });
    }
  }, [currentRecord, setCurrentRecord, form]);


<Form.Item
  label="Birthday"
  name="birthday"
  rules={[
    { required: true, message: "Please select a birthday!" }
  ]}
>
  <DatePicker
    style={{ width: "100%" }}
    placeholder="Select your birthday"
    // you cal also use an array with all formats your field should accept
    // eg.: ['YYYY-MM-DD', 'YY-MM-DD', 'DD-MM-YY']
    format={'YYYY-MM-DD'} 
  />
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: now working, same issue. `Unhandled Runtime Error`
`TypeError: date.locale is not a function` on NextJs 13